# How to get another child element by classname of the parent div of a element that triggered a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

my problem sounds pretty simple. I have  divs with no id and class specified like this

```
<div style="position:relative; float:left">
    <input type="text" onfocus="renderCalendar(event);" size="50" id="cal" name="cal">
    <div class="wrappercal calwrapper">
        <div class="yearmonth">
            <table class="caltable"><tbody>
            <tr><th width="80%" scope="col" colspan="5">
                <select class="dtcombo year" onchange="changeCalendar()">
                    <option value="2000">2000</option>
                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select onchange="changeCalendar()" class="dtcombo month">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                 </select></th>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

There may be several similar divs in the page

I have a javascript function

```
function renderCalendar(event){
    var triggerer=event.target.id; // THIS WILL GIVE THE ID OF TEXTBOX THAT TRIGGERED THIS FUNCTION.
  $("#"+triggerer).parent().children(".wrappercal").children(".yearmonth").children(".caltable").children(".year").val(); //not working
}
```

The nest follows like this

```
  Parent Div > wrappercal(div) > yearmonth(div) > caltable(table) > year(select)
```

my problem is to get value of combo with class "year" of the parent div of textbox that triggered the function.

Can anybody figure out where i went wrong? any suggestions?

P.S. Please bear I m not good with dom elements.

Thanks

Comment: try the .parent().find(".class name ") its the simple one

Comment: @RegisteredUser, I have thought that, but isn't it slower than the one i tried.

Comment: @RegisteredUser, I think i should go with `find`, the speed seems to be negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try this?

```
function renderCalendar(event){
    $(event.target).parent().find(".wrappercal .yearmonth .caltable .year").val(); 
}
```

Can you check (using `console.log(event.target)` and tracking) that the target element is really what/where it should be?

**EDIT**

The problem is that `children()` only searches through one level (deep) of child nodes and there is multiple levels between `.caltable` and `.year` (`<tr><th>...`). Use `find()` instead (which will search recursively through your nodes). ;-)

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/children/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Following

```
         function renderCalendaer(event) {

           $("#"+event.target.id).parent().find(".year").val();   

                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$("#"+triggerer).parent().find(".year").val() instead.
```